# How can I create an iOS OTA Manifest file using plistbuddy?

Tags: ios, plist

I would like to create an iOS Manifest file for distributing Ad-Hoc and Enterprise build iOS app over the air.

Ideally I could use plistbuddy to automate this so it can be created by a build script.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished like so.  There are a few optional parts of this manifest I left out including the App Icon.  This is the minimum to get it to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Creates an iOS OTA (Over the Air) Manifest File

URL="https://sywl.theappguy.guru/relayrunner/0.2.6/RunnerApp_0.2.6ent.ipa"
BUNDLE_ID="com.example.yourbundleid"
BUNDLE_VERSION="0.0.1"
TITLE="Your App Name"
FILE="yourmanifestfile.plist"

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :items array" {FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :items:0:assets array" {FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :items:0:assets:0::kind string software-package" {FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :items:0:assets:0::url string ${URL}" {FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :items:0:metadata:bindle-identifer string ${BUNDLE_ID}" {FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :items:0:metadata:bundle-version string ${BUNDLE_VERSION}" {FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :items:0:metadata:kind string software" {FILE}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :items:0:metadata:title string ${TITLE}" {FILE}
```

I have published this as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/bradtheappguy/f0e42946269ed2748e68